# Node webkit (chromium) on a limited Redhat

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, webkit, chromium

For my work, I've made a tool in javascript using nodejs webkit (to simply pass out the limit of javascript without a server). But I have a problem :

- The environment is very secured where I need to install the tool, the OS is redhat enterprise 5.2 (very old).
- I've made a package with node webkit builder (to have the node libraries and chromium in the same file), but when I try to launch the executable, there is a missing library : libx11-xcb.so.1.

The solution is simple, I can do a yum install of the library but yum and apt-get is not activated (because high security).. So how  can i install the missing library manually ?

Thank you !